# Keep table from expanding when text is input with PHP

Tags: php, css, html-table, overflow

I have the below nested table and am setting the text content of one of the tds with PHP. Everything works fine except that when the text exceeds the size of the table the table expands. I want to prevent that but `style="overflow:hidden"` doesn't seem to be working.

```
<table id="mainEditTable" style="overflow:hidden" width="826px" border="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td class="mainEntryRowVis" id="guestEntries1"><table style="overflow:hidden" class="gstTblPad" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th width="100%" scope="col">Delete old GDOCS</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="nmBldrEntry" onclick="selectText('nbe1');" id="nbe1"><?php echo $_POST["deleteGdocs"];?></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the text being set to the td `>IR#31.XX#32.XX#39.XX#310.XX#33.XX#34.XX#311.XX#312.XX#35.XX#36.XX#313.XX#314.XX#37.XX#38.XX#315.XX#316.XX#5NAMEBUILDER#ER`

Here are the CSS classes directly affecting the table:

```
.gstTblPad th{
    background-color: #D2D0D0;
    color: #666;
    padding:5px; 
}


.mainEntryRowVis{
    border: thin solid #999;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    table-style:fixed;
}

.nmBldrEntry{
    padding: 15px;
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Update: Any way to do this without the th elements being affected?
[image]

Comment: See [this article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200704/how_to_prevent_html_tables_from_becoming_too_wide/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `table-layout:fixed;` as css property-value-pair for your table. Then use `overflow:hidden` on the tds of this table.

see http://jsfiddle.net/uAhN8/

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without the tr element's cetered text being offset like is shown in my edit above?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give it a max-width. That worked for me.

```
max-width: 100px;

/* additional */
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
```

Break-word means the text will wrap to next line. I don't know if you need it.